# How to delete project with a trailing whitespace from gerrit

Tags: git, gerrit

I'm trying to remove the project from Gerrit of version 2.16.2 without success.

The project is created (by mistake) with a trailing space: "ui "

I do have a "delete-project" plugin installed, and use the command:

```
ssh -p 29418 <my-user>@<ip-of-my-gerrit-server> delete-project delete --yes-really-delete "ui%20"
```

But it responds with:

```
fatal: project ui%20 not found
```

I've also tried other options like:

```
"ui"
"ui%20"
"ui "
"ui+"
"ui*"
// the same as above with single quotes or without quotes at all
```

Nothing works and the same error appears over and over again. So the question is what is the exact command I should use in this case?

I've always tried to delete the project via UI, but it returns 404 page, so probably it doesn't work.

This is an empty repository and I don't have any reviews on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deleting projects with "non-conventional" names does not seem to be directly supported by gerrit at the moment (June 2021).

Cases in point:

- [Issue 14105](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/gerrit/issues/detail?id=14105&q=delete-project&can=2): "Unable to delete project with ampersand in name", reported in Feb. 2021.
- [Issue 14048](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/gerrit/issues/detail?id=14048&q=delete-project&can=2): "When the project name is created with '-' at the beginning, it cannot be deleted by gerrit 'Delete Project' menu or ssh command."

Comment: Thanks a lot! Are there any workarounds (maybe manual deletion or renaming somehow the repo)? I'm not really familiar with gerrit - only as a casual user...

Comment: @MarkBramnik Me too (casual user). Looking at commits like https://github.com/GerritCodeReview/gerrit/commit/b39b794a3948878f8109288545b7e16831cdab53, I would try and understand what DeleteProject does before trying to replicate that manully on the server side.

Comment: Ok, I see, thanks a lot. I've upvoted, and will accept the answer in a couple of days or so if I won't be lucky enough to get additional answers with a workaround from people who develop the delete plugin before actually digging into that by myself - kind of out of scope for me for now.